# Is there a way of grouping rows together as parent/children with show/hide in Datatables.js without using custom JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using datatables.js (version 1.10.25) to create a table in my CMS. My issue is that I am showing/hiding some of the rows of the table under a heading row using jQuery and this breaks the sorting of the table.

[image]

Is there a way of grouping rows together as parent/children with show/hide in datatables.js without using custom JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here are two options:

Option 1, [Datatables Row grouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html), it does not allow to hide/show children in groups (or at least I think).

Option 2, [Datatables Child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), the same but it allows to hide/show children in groups.

Always use plugins whenever you can, don't reinvent the wheel ^^